# ItemAdded Event Receiver is not triggered when item is added by workflow

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

I am debugging on SP2010 environment. There is an Event receiver listening to particular list, the first few lines of code is:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPList listOfEntries = properties.List;
                if (listOfEntries.Title == "Command")
```

I added a breakpoint at the line "SPList listOfEntries = properties.List".

When I added an item to "Command" list manually, the breakpoint will be reached.

There is a SPD list workflow and the workflow create a task asking for approval. If the user reject the task immediately after the task is assigned, a new item will be added to "Command" list by the workflow. <strike>In this way, the Event Receiver will not be triggered (the breakpoint will not be reached, too).</strike> 
I change the VS debugger to monitor OWSTimer and this time breakpoint is reached. On visual studio debug screen I mouseover every variable inside this function. I found all variables are carrying the wrong item! For example,

```
SPList myList = web.Lists["ListA"];
SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
myQuery.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name = \"Title\"/>" + "<Value Type = \"Text\">"
```

In VS debug mode, "myList" is carrying "ListZ" (which is not within this function). myQuery is carrying web.Lists["ListA"]. All variable goes crazy. 
That's why my event receiver not work??! Or actually my VS have bug?

If the user wait for 3 minutes before reject the task, the same item will be added to "Command" list by the workflow, the Event Receiver will be triggered this time.

If I check with VS debugger in this situation, all variables show normal value....

<strike>It doesn't make sense to me. If my event receiver code have bug, it should at least reach the breakpoint. However it is not fired at all...</strike>

Do you have any clue on what is happening?

Comment: Is runwithelevatedprivilegesused ? If yes, then SPD workflow will not trigger.

Comment: Do you have any SPD workflow attached on "Command" list ?

Comment: @MonicaJagani, I don't find "runwithelevatedprivilegesused" in the code and the designer workflow. Also, no SPD workflow attached at command list.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but can you try to change the sequence number of the event receiver (check element.xml). It might help but not sure.

Comment: Have you looked for any clues in the ULS logs ?

Comment: @HarryB, there is no exception in ULS. That is most annoying.

Comment: I have updated my new finding about debugger

Answer (score 1):

i think your battling between  asynchronous vs asynchronous events occurring that your trying to capture.

the problem is you have a workflow which is independent of the list events.

quickest and simplest solution is to have a wait for 3 or 5 minutes delay before sending out the task message to the user giving time for the workflow event to complete and for the event to trigger.

Comment: I agree it would be a feasible work around. But why the event receiver is not fired at all? Will it just ignore some event when it is busy?

Comment: what EventReceiver Class are you using?

Comment: I have updated my new finding about debugger.
class SPItemEventReceiver is using.